# как резаный / как резаному

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, будьте добры, "ему хотелось кричать как резаному / как резаный"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот вариант выглядит некорректно.

Фразеологический оборот может использоваться в такой конструкции: он кричит (кричал) как резаный (как будто ***он*** резаный). Это как бы мнение наблюдателя со стороны.

Поэтому предлагается замена: ***Ему хотелось криком кричать — громко, истошно, так, словно его режут.***

То есть надо подобрать подходящий синоним.